# Merge Two Columns in R, Fill in NAs with Value

Tags: r, merge

I have merge two datasets on the variable Name in R. I need a way to combine the School.x and School.y columns so that the NA fields are filled in by the other column. I assume there is some easy way in R to do this- anyone have ideas?

Image of a sample of the merged data below (couldn't paste the table for some reason.)

[image]

Bonus if you can figure out how to make it so that if School.x and School.y both have a value, the merged column just takes the default value from School.x 
(For example, if Chloe was listed as attending Lincoln in School.x but Lincoln High in School.y, I just want the column to default to Lincoln.)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Bonus if you can figure out how to post a reproducible example. [Here's a hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?s=1|12.5600)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should do the trick.  I modified the third row of your sample data frame to be a case where both `School.x` and `School.y` have non NA values, to demonstrate the bonus part of your question.

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c("Adam", "Bob", "Jane", "Bill", "Chloe", "Mandy"),
                 School.x=c("Hillcrest", NA, "Irvington", NA, "Lincoln", NA),
                 School.y=c(NA, "Star Academy", "Star Academy", "Mission Hills", NA,
                            "Washington Middle"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


# choose default value from 'School.x' in the case that both 'School.x' and
# 'School.y' have values
df$merged[!is.na(df$School.x) & !is.na(df$School.y)] <-
    df$School.x[!is.na(df$School.x) & !is.na(df$School.y)]

# replace NA values in 'School.x' with values from 'School.y' and vice-versa
df$merged[is.na(df$School.x)] <- df$School.y[is.na(df$School.x)]
df$merged[is.na(df$School.y)] <- df$School.x[is.na(df$School.y)]

> df
   Name  School.x          School.y            merged
1  Adam Hillcrest              <NA>         Hillcrest
2   Bob      <NA>      Star Academy      Star Academy
3  Jane Irvington      Star Academy         Irvington
4  Bill      <NA>     Mission Hills     Mission Hills
5 Chloe   Lincoln              <NA>           Lincoln
6 Mandy      <NA> Washington Middle Washington Middle
```

Comment: And add `df$School.y[!is.na(df$School.x) & !is.na(df$School.y)] <- df$School.x[!is.na(df$School.x) & !is.na(df$School.y)]` or something like that as the first line for the "bonus".

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!